# Is there a curve such that it's parametrization r(t) has κ → ∞ as t → ∞?

Tags: calculus, curves, parametrization

I thought this question was easy but I can't think of a proper example. I've tried (e^t, e^-t, 1), (sin(t), cos(t), 1), and many many different variations of these. The closest I got to was (t, e^t, t+1) which has a limit of sqrt(2)/infinity. But since that equals 0, that's useless. Is there a way to find a parameterization that only has 't' in the numerator. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $\kappa$?

Comment: The curvature of a parameterization

Comment: Something like $(e^{-e^t}\cos t, e^{-e^t}\sin t,0)$ should work.

Comment: You, good man, are a genius. That question is surprisingly hard. THANKS!